# Traverse Binary Search Tree Pre Order recursively

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I am trying to traverse a BST Pre-Order recursively but I can not make it work. This is what I've tried:

```
public String PreOrder() {
    return preOrderStringBuild(root, "");
}

public String preOrderStringBuild(Node root, String preOrderString) {
    if (root == null) {
        return "";
    }

    preOrderString += root.key + " "; 
    preOrderStringBuild(root.left, preOrderString);
    preOrderStringBuild(root.right, preOrderString);            

    return preOrderString;
}
```

But this only gives me the first Element... What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Strings are immutable. Assign preOrderString to the string returned by the recursive call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, method parameters are passed *by value*, and strings are *immutable*.

That  means that this line of code does not change the string that is passed into the method, instead it creates a new string, that can only be seen in the current call of the method:

```
preOrderString += root.key + " ";
```

One way to fix this is to use a *mutable* string type like StringBuilder instead of String. Changes to mutable objects are visible outside the method.

```
public String preOrderStringBuild(Node root, StringBuilder preOrderString) {
    ...
    preOrderString.append(root.key + " "); // instead of preOrderString = ...
    ...
```

Another way is to  way to fix this is make sure you use the value returned from the recursive calls. Going by this route you don't even need to pass in the string you are building.

```
public String preOrderStringBuild(Node root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return "";
    }

    String preOrderString = root.key + " " 
        + preOrderStringBuild(root.left) 
        + preOrderStringBuild(root.right);

    return preOrderString;
}
```

Comment: that was it! Thanks :)